# Want custom title for facebook share link

Tags: php, facebook

I have a custom title I want my facebook share to accept. I got the share plugin from http://www.addtoany.com. I have followed some of the links to on the forum but to no success. I have added in the correct metas but to no success. When I click on the facebook button and it takes me to the page it only displays " in " and not my php variables as shown below:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<?php $mytitle = $type." ".$status." in ".$province; ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1050, user-scalable = yes" />
<meta name="title" content="<?php echo $mytitle;  ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that your variables contain the correct content?

Comment: var_dump($mytitle), what it shows?

Comment: Yes am sure because as I open my page the Title on my browser shows the variable values

Comment: Might be some other place where title is being set correct. try <?php $mytitle = 'testing ....'; ?>  does it works?

Comment: Yes it does work but still not taking the variables

Comment: Thats it. Check your these variables thouroghly $type, $status and $province.

Answer (score 0):

Try
First double sure, that $type, $status and $province are not empty or null. and also change meta tag of title as below.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<?php $mytitle = $type." ".$status." in ".$province; ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1050, user-scalable = yes" />

<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $mytitle;  ?>"/>

<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```